# what is the compatible version of ng2-dragula with angular 13?

Tags: angular

what's the compatible version of ng2-dragular with angular 13,the latest version 5.0.1 doesn't work, and I searched in npmjs I didn't find the sol

install version 5.0.1 it doesn't work
npm i ng2-dragula I got a lot of error when Install v5.0.1

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.